# How to prevent html to insert space when a linebreak + indent is made

Tags: html

I have this code:

```
        <a href="#"><img src="img/fb.png"></a>
        <img src="sprtr.png">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/twit.png"></a>
        <img src="sprtr.png">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/tumb.png"></a>
        <img src="img/sprtr.png">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/yout.png"></a>
```

which displays such

[image]

when I rewrite it like this:

```
<a href="#"><img src="img/fb.png"></a><img src="img/sprtr.png"><a href="#"><img src="img/twit.png"></a><img src="img/sprtr.png"><a href="#"><img src="img/tumb.png"></a><img src="img/sprtr.png"><a href="#"><img src="img/yout.png"></a>
```

it displays such

[image]

Is there anyway I can keep my stuff indented and still achieve the second result?
Somehow tell html parser not to add spaces?

Comment: Try self-closing your `<img />` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways to overcome this issue, each with their pros and cons. The solutions are as follows:

## 1) CSS - *somewhat of a hack*

The space is appearing due to the images being `display:inline;`. This can be overcome as follows:

```
/* CSS */
.social img {display:block;float:left;}
```

***assuming***

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="social">
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<img src="#">
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
</div>
```

## 2) CSS - *partially unsupported, CSS4*

```
/* CSS */
.social {text-space-collapse:discard;}
```

***assuming***

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="social">
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<img src="#">
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
</div>
```

***Note:** See [CSS Text Level 4 Specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css4-text/#white-space-collapsing).*

## 3) Comments - *poor readability*

```
<!-- HTML -->
   <a href="#"><img src="#"></a><!--  
--><img src="sprtr.png"><!--  
--><a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
```

## 4) Backend language - *only works if using one*

***assuming PHP***

```
<?php
 echo '<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>';
 echo '<img src="#">';
 echo '<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using CSS you could; but it's a hack. Annoying as it is, whitespace IS sometimes important in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS Text Level 3 specifications added in a [`text-space-collapse`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-text-20120119/#white-space-collapsing) property for this specific scenario, but it isn't currently implemented in any browsers (that I know of). You would use it like this:

```
div {
    text-space-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Where all line breaks would be collapsed into "nothing" inside divisions, so long as there are no physical spaces between the elements (only line breaks).

Aside from that, no there is no pretty way to do this. The nicest solution (I think) is to float the elements to the left so there isn't space between them.

Comment: According to the CSS Text Level 3 draft, `text-space-collapse: collapse` is the default and corresponds to current behavior. It means that consecutive whitespace is collapsed to a single space. So it would not help even if it were implemented.

Comment: @Jukka: Not true. While I admit the rules for that property are *very* confusing, it *is* possible to collapse all space into nothing.

Comment: wow I really didn't think this was an actual limitation... it seems so basic... Thanks for looking it up with me, I'll keep the question open for a while in case somebody finds anything out

Comment: @animuson, @joon - `discard` would be the appropriate value for `text-space-collapse`, but it isn't defined until CSS Text Level 4. As for using `collapse`, it only works if there is a zero-width space (`U+200B` or `&#8203;`) immediately preceding it (but all spaces are removed that come before or after a line feed, so it seems to be impossible). If it is possible, adding `&#8203;` after each would be necessary (or possibly the actual character, rather than the entity, but entity should be good).

Answer (score 0):

You may use HTML comments to keep indentation if you really want to. Just like this:

```
    <a href="#"><img src="img/fb.png"></a><!--
    --><img src="sprtr.png"><!--
    --><a href="#"><img src="img/twit.png"></a><-- ...
```

But the legibility of this is rather poor...